# Как прервать линию при передаче координат мыши через сокет?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Сайт онлайн доска на которой рисуют несколько пользователей.

По сокету передаются координаты мыши и при получении отображаются на стороне клиента, на канвасе. Но когда пользователь отпускает мышь, beginPath() работает только для стороны, которая рисует в этот момент. А для остальных линия не прерывается. Пробовал много чего, не получается.

Код

```
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // canvas.width = 1100;
    // canvas.height = 600;
    var x, y;

    function drawii(event, x, y) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';

        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/chat/'
            + roomName
            + '/'
        );

        chatSocket.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log("соединение установлено");
        }

        chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
            const dataa = JSON.parse(e.data);
            var imgg = dataa.message;
            var pixelsArray = imgg;
            drawii(event, pixelsArray[0], pixelsArray[1]);
        };

        chatSocket.onclose = function (e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };

        function waitForSocketConnection(chatSocket, callback) {
            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    if (chatSocket.readyState === 1) {
                        if (callback !== undefined) {
                            callback();
                        }
                        return;
                    } else {
                        waitForSocketConnection(chatSocket, callback);
                    }
                }, 2);
        };

        waitForSocketConnection(chatSocket, function () {
            canvas.onmousedown = function (event) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                canvas.onmousemove = function (event) {
                    x = event.clientX;
                    y = event.clientY;
                    var array = [x, y];
                    var message = array;
                    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                        'message': message
                    }));
                }
            }
            canvas.onmouseup = function () {
                canvas.onmousemove = null;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос вместо скриншотов

Comment: @DarthKYL добавил

Comment: Вы уже пробовали при вызывании события поднятия клавиши мыши отправлять информацию об этом второму пользователю и как-либо реагировать на это?